# Django: filter by ForeignKey - ValueError too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Tags: python, django, сериализация

Есть модель `Snippet`:

```
###models.py
class SnippetManager(models.Manager):
    def create_snippet(self, title, text, author, tags):
    snippet = self.create(title=title,text=text,author=author,tags=tags)
    return snippet

class Snippet(models.Model):
    sid = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='snippets')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    tags = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    objects = SnippetManager()

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('data:snippet_detail',
                    args=[self.sid])

def __str__(self):
    return self.title

class Meta:
    ordering = ('-updated',)
```

urls.py:

```
###urls.py
from . import views as apiviews
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url(r'^users/(?P<authorid>)[0-9]+/$', apiviews.SnippetFilteredView.filter_snippets, name='authorid'),
    url(r'^users/test/$', apiviews.SnippetFilteredView2.filter_snippets, name='test'), 
    ...
]
```

views.py:

```
###views.py
class SnippetFilteredView(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = SnippetSerializer

    def filter_snippets(request, authorid):
        queryset = Snippet.objects.filter(author_id=authorid)
        return queryset

class SnippetFilteredView2(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = SnippetSerializer

    def filter_snippets(request):
      u1 = User.objects.get(id=1)
      queryset = u1.snippets.all()
      return queryset
```

serializers.py:

```
###serializers.py
from data.models import Snippet, SnippetManager
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework import serializers

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'email', 'is_active')

class SnippetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Snippet
        fields = ('sid', 'author', 'title', 'updated', 'tags')

class SnippetFullSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Snippet
        fields = ('sid', 'title', 'text', 'author', 'created', 'updated', 'tags')
```

Проблема при фильтрации по сниппетам, принадлежащим конкретному пользователю. при вводе */api/users/1* (`id` пользователей просто инкремент 1,2...) выбивает:

> ```
> ValueError invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
> ```

если попробовать функцию из `test`, ошибка:

> ```
> ValueError too many values to unpack (expected 2).
> ```

Модель пользователя стандартная. Прошу подсказать, как сделать необходимую выборку.

Traceback второй ошибки

```
Environment:
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://192.168.0.100/api/users/1/

Django Version: 2.1.3
Python Version: 3.6.6
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'rest_framework.authtoken',
 'rest_framework',
 'rest_auth',
 'data',
 'api']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']

Traceback:
File "/home/styr/snipper-backend/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
 34.             response = get_response(request)

File "/home/styr/snipper-backend/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py" in __call__
 93.             response = self.process_response(request, response)

File "/home/styr/snipper-backend/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/middleware/clickjacking.py" in process_response
 26.         if response.get('X-Frame-Options') is not None:

File "/home/styr/snipper-backend/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in get
 390.         clone = self.filter(*args, **kwargs)

File "/home/styr/snipper-backend/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in filter
 844.         return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/styr/snipper-backend/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _filter_or_exclude
 862.             clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))

File "/home/styr/snipper-backend/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in add_q
 1263.         clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)

File "/home/styr/snipper-backend/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in _add_q
 1287.                     split_subq=split_subq,

File "/home/styr/snipper-backend/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in build_filter
 1161.         arg, value = filter_expr

Exception Type: ValueError at /api/users/1/
Exception Value: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Comment: По второй ошибке можете привести traceback?

Comment: работает, теперь ошибки одинаковые, пост дополнил

Answer (score 0):

У вас в `urls.py` в регулярном выражении группа `authorid` не захватывает условие выборки, т. е. получается что она всегда будет равна пустой строке. Попробуйте так:

```python
url(r'^users/(?P<authorid>[0-9]+)/$', ... )
```

Comment: работает, теперь ошибки одинаковые, пост дополнил